# django form exclude a user instance from a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I have the following model:

class UserProfile(models.Model):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="user")
people_interested = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="interested")
```

Now I want a form where I want to offer users a form where they can choose people_interested, so I add the following forms.py

```
class ChooseForm(forms.Form):
    q_set = User.objects.all()
    peers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset = q_set)
```

and then in views:

```
form = ChooseForm(data = request.POST or None)
if request.POST and form.is_valid():
    uprofile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    uprofile.people_interested = form.cleaned_data['peers']
    uprofile.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
else:
    return render(request, "form_polls.html", {'form':form})
```

But the trouble with this is, the current user instance also gets displayed. So I tried the following in views.py:

```
form = ChooseForm(request.user.id, data = request.POST or None)
```

and then in forms.py

```
class ChooseForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, uid, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChooseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['peers'].queryset = User.objects.exclude(id=uid)
    q_set = User.objects.all() 
    peers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset = q_set)
```

But the above is not a clean implementation, is there a better method of doing it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you say this is not a clean implementation? Overwriting `queryset` on `__init__` is perfectly acceptable.

The only things I'd do to improve your code is using a `post_save` signal on `User` to create it's `UserProfile`, then just do `user.get_profile()` on your view. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910359/creating-a-extended-user-profile)

You could also use a `ModelForm` for `UserProfile` instead of a regular form, and limit the fields to `people_interested`.

Comment: the bad part i think is       `self.fields['peers'].queryset = User.objects.exclude(id=uid)
    q_set = User.objects.all()` first you exclude in `__init__` method and then again doing a `User.object.all()` any way to have the exclude current user, here itself.

Comment: You can't exclude there, you should exclude at the __init__. This is perfectly valid, check out this similar question, they resolve it in the same way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539358/django-model-forms-filter-queryset